# JSON JSON_EXTRACT with MySQL

Tags: mysql, json, database

I'm using the JSON_EXTRACT with MYSQL and using this command:

```
SET @j = '{"id" : "1"}';
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(@j, '$.id')
```

the result is

```
"1"
```

but, when I use

```
SET @j = '[{"id" : "1"}, {"id" : "2"}]';
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(@j, '$.id')
```

the result is

```
NULL
```

I expected this result

```
"1"
"2"
```

Any sugestion? I want the list of ID'S from JSON.

Comment: you're using two different types of objects. the first is an object that would have an `id` property. the second is an array. you need to loop through the array first to access each id

Comment: `If it is possible that those arguments could return multiple values, the matched values are autowrapped as an array, in the order corresponding to the paths that produced them.`, see [JSON_EXTRACT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-extract). See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fEn38oLaod4WCtnCJeDmFM/0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
SET @j = '[{"id" : "1"}, {"id" : "2"}]';
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(@j,'$[*].id')
```

the result is:

```
["1", "2"]
```